# Django - creaing a custom model admin form field, passing the model instance to set a read only attribute

Tags: django

I know you can set readonly_fields in a model's admin.py but I am trying to make a field read only dependent upon it's (saved) value in the database.

I can create a custom field Class, but am unable to pass the value of the model instance so I can achieve the above.

Eg

```
class MytypeField(models.CharField):

  def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):

    PAGE_LAYOUT_CHOICES = (
        ('column1','One Column'),
        ('column2','Two Columns')
    )

    kwargs['max_length'] = 7
    kwargs['choices'] = PAGE_LAYOUT_CHOICES
    kwargs['default'] = 'column1'

    super(MytypeField,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
```

And in the model

```
    layout = MytypeField()
```

Is there a way to do this in admin.py rather than in the model itself? I can't pass the model instance to this custom class, and I'm sure that's not the way to do it anyway!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can in model admin, model admin has the method `get_readonly_fields`:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj and obj.layout:
            return self.readonly_fields + ('layout', )
        return self.readonly_fields
```